# What is the minimal set of packages required to transform a LaTeX file to a PDF?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, pdf, latex

I have a plain LaTeX file which I want to compile to a PDF. I see that people suggest `texlive-full` for this task. At the same time, it weights ridiculous amount of memory.

```
$ apt-get install texlive-full 
.....
Need to get 2586 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5304 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I don't think that such a simple operation (compiling a `.tex` file to a `.pdf`) should really require such a huge set of packages.

**Q:** What is the minimal set of packages required to compile a `.tex` (LaTeX) file to a `.pdf`?

Answer (score 3):

Start with `texlive-latex-base`. If TeX complains about missing files use "Search the contents of packages" at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find the package that provides it.